# Determine whether a character is not in a set of parenthesis at an index?

Tags: python

I'm trying to determine whether a character is not enclosed by a set of parenthesis at a specific index in string s. Suppose:

```
s = '(A.(B|A)).A'
```

Then the indexes of the character '.' are 2 and 9. However, only '.' at index 9 (i.e. s[9]) is NOT enclosed in a set parenthesis. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: I want to know the index at which the character is NOT in enclosed in parenthesis as well.

Comment: Do you want the indexes?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: Will the parentheses always be balanced?

Comment: Do you want all the characters which are not enclosed in parenthesis or only specific characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This works only if the parenthesis are balanced.

If you are looking for specific characters' indexes, which are not enclosed by parenthesis, then you can do something like this

```
def checker(data, char_checked):
    opened, result = 0, []
    for idx, char in enumerate(data):
        if char == char_checked and opened == 0 and char != "(":
            result.append(idx)
        if char == "(":
            opened += 1
        elif char == ")":
            opened -= 1
    return result

assert checker('(A.(B|A)).A', '.')  == [9]
assert checker('(A.(B|A)).A', 'A')  == [10]
assert checker('(A.(B|A)).A', 'C')  == []
```

If you are looking for all the characters which are not enclosed in parenthesis, then you can alter it a little like this

```
def checker(data):
    opened, result = 0, []
    for idx, char in enumerate(data):
        if opened == 0 and char != "(":
            result.append([idx, char])
        if char == "(":
            opened += 1
        elif char == ")":
            opened -= 1
    return result

assert checker('(A.(B|A)).A') == [[9, '.'], [10, 'A']]
assert checker('(A.(B|A))')   == []
```

Comment: what if the parens aren't balanced, like @jonrsharpe asked? maybe it should be checking if `opened <= 0`?

Comment: @acushner It means that, its closed more than once. Technically that is also unbalanced. I made a note in the answer about this. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: also, i'm wrong. it really should be `opened = max(0, opened)` because if you have something like `')))))))(A)'` that should be enclosed

Comment: To clear up the balancing issue, I perform a check before this one that determines if it's balanced or not. Thus, again, this answer is just perfect!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for `'.'` at indexes `x` and `y` of any string would be:

```
print '(' in my_string[:x] and ')' in my_string[x+1:]
```

If this evaluates to True it means that the character at index x is enclosed by a set of parentheses.

You can test for the index y respectively

Hope that helped,

Cheers! Alex

Comment: This wouldn't work for e.g. `'(A).(B)'`, although it's not clear what we can rely on in the OP's data

Comment: That's true.. I approached the question by speculating that any '(' before the character and any ')' after the character would make the character enclosed. I'm not sure I can confirm that it would work for wongg's problem though